# Unable to launch express with npm start

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

How do I correctly create and launch express with npm start? When I do "npm start" I get the following error. `Failed at the webserver@1.0.0 start script.` I see the following in the error log that hints to the app.js but what is it about the app.js that is incorrect? Thank you.

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error webserver@1.0.0 start: `./src/app.js`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the webserver@1.0.0 start script.
```

I have the following package.json file.

```
{
    "name": "webserver",
    "preferGlobal": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Milton Centeno <centem@gmail.com>",
    "description": "a simple express web server",
    "license": "MIT",
    "main" : "./src/app.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": ">=4.15.3"
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the tree command that shows where my app.js file is relative to package.json.

```
.
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    └── app.js
```

And this is what I have for my app.js

```
// Load the Express package as a module
const express = require("express");

// Access the exported service
const app = express();

// Return a string for requests to the root URL ("/")
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express!");
});

// Start listening to incoming requests
// If process.env.PORT is not defined, port number 3000 is used
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a `start` script: `"start": "node src/app.js",`.

From the [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-start):

> This runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's `"start"` property of its `"scripts"` object. If no `"start"` property is specified on the `"scripts"` object, it will run `node server.js`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had to add node before the src/app.js.